# Java Connect Four Bug

Tags: java

I am learning Java and have encountered a bug I cannot seem to fix. It is a console based connect four game. The issue I have is that the methods that check for a win don't seem to be working properly. I have established that it is a problem with the methods themselves and not the parameters being submitted. Anyone other general tips would be greatly appreciated, as this is my first program. Thanks! The code is below.

```
package com.coleriggle.java;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Game {

private static boolean running;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game game = new Game();

    game.startGame();
}

private void startGame() {

    BoardHandler boardHandlerObject = new BoardHandler();
    Game gameObject = new Game();
    SelectionHandler selectionHandlerObject = new SelectionHandler();

    gameObject.startingDialogue();
    boardHandlerObject.setNewBoard();
    boardHandlerObject.refreshBoard();

    running = true;

    while (running) {

        selectionHandlerObject.startSelection();
    }

}

private void startingDialogue() {

    GraphicsHandler graphicsHandlerObject = new GraphicsHandler();

    graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("Welcome to Connect Four!", 0);
    graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("Player X will go first!", 0);
    graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("", 3);
}

public void announceWin(char player) {

    GraphicsHandler graphicsHandlerObject = new GraphicsHandler();

    graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("Player " + player
            + " has won!", 0);

    running = false;
}

}

class GraphicsHandler {

public int outputTextToScreen(String text, int newLineType) {

    if (newLineType == 0) {

        System.out.println(text);

        return 0;
    }

    else if (newLineType == 1) {

        System.out.print(text);

        return 1;
    }

    else if (newLineType == 2) {

        System.out.print("\n" + text);

        return 2;
    }

    else if (newLineType == 3) {

        System.out.println();

        return 3;
    }

    else {
        return 4;
    }
}

protected void drawBoardToScreen() {

    BoardHandler boardHandlerObject = new BoardHandler();

    char[][] tempGameBoard = boardHandlerObject.getGameBoard();

    System.out.println("|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |");
    System.out.println("|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|");

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println("|  " + tempGameBoard[i][0] + "  |  "
                + tempGameBoard[i][1] + "  |  " + tempGameBoard[i][2]
                + "  |  " + tempGameBoard[i][3] + "  |  "
                + tempGameBoard[i][4] + "  |  " + tempGameBoard[i][5]
                + "  |  " + tempGameBoard[i][6] + "  |  ");
    }

    System.out.println("|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|");

}

}

class BoardHandler {

GraphicsHandler graphicsHandlerObject = new GraphicsHandler();

private static char[][] gameBoard = {
        { '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' },
        { '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' },
        { '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' },
        { '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' },
        { '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' },
        { '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?' } };

public char[][] getGameBoard() {

    return gameBoard;
}

public void setNewBoard() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            gameBoard[i][j] = '?';
        }
    }
}

public void refreshBoard() {

    graphicsHandlerObject.drawBoardToScreen();
}

public void replaceSelectionOfBoard(int row, int column, char player) {

    BoardHandler.gameBoard[row][column] = player;
}

public int checkSelectionValidity(int columnSubmitted, char currentPlayer) {

    BoardHandler boardHandlerObject = new BoardHandler();
    WinCheckHandler winCheckHandlerObject = new WinCheckHandler();
    Game gameObject = new Game();

    char[][] tempGameBoard = boardHandlerObject.getGameBoard();
    ;

    int column;

    column = columnSubmitted -= 1;

    if (tempGameBoard[5][columnSubmitted] == '?') {

        if (winCheckHandlerObject.checkForWin(5, column, currentPlayer) ==   1)     {

            gameObject.announceWin(currentPlayer);
        }

        boardHandlerObject
                .replaceSelectionOfBoard(5, column, currentPlayer);

        return 0;
    }

    else if (tempGameBoard[4][columnSubmitted] == '?') {

        if (winCheckHandlerObject.checkForWin(4, column, currentPlayer) == 1)     {

            gameObject.announceWin(currentPlayer);

        }

        boardHandlerObject
                .replaceSelectionOfBoard(4, column, currentPlayer);

        return 0;
    }

    else if (tempGameBoard[3][columnSubmitted] == '?') {

        if (winCheckHandlerObject.checkForWin(3, column, currentPlayer) == 1)     {

            gameObject.announceWin(currentPlayer);

        }

        boardHandlerObject
                .replaceSelectionOfBoard(3, column, currentPlayer);

        return 0;
    }

    else if (tempGameBoard[2][columnSubmitted] == '?') {

        if (winCheckHandlerObject.checkForWin(2, column, currentPlayer) == 1)     {

            gameObject.announceWin(currentPlayer);

        }

        boardHandlerObject
                .replaceSelectionOfBoard(2, column, currentPlayer);

        return 0;
    }

    else if (tempGameBoard[1][columnSubmitted] == '?') {

        if (winCheckHandlerObject.checkForWin(1, column, currentPlayer) == 1)     {

            gameObject.announceWin(currentPlayer);

        }

        boardHandlerObject
                .replaceSelectionOfBoard(1, column, currentPlayer);

        return 0;
    }

    else if (tempGameBoard[0][columnSubmitted] == '?') {

        if (winCheckHandlerObject.checkForWin(0, column, currentPlayer) == 1)     {

            gameObject.announceWin(currentPlayer);

        }

        boardHandlerObject
                .replaceSelectionOfBoard(0, column, currentPlayer);

        return 0;
    }

    else {

        return 1;
    }

}

}

class TurnHandler {

private char currentTurn = 'X';

public char getCurrentTurn() {

    return currentTurn;
}

public void changeCurrentTurn() {

    if (currentTurn == 'X') {

        currentTurn = 'O';
    }

    else if (currentTurn == 'O') {

        currentTurn = 'X';
    }
}

}

class SelectionHandler {

TurnHandler turnHandlerObject = new TurnHandler();
GraphicsHandler graphicsHandlerObject = new GraphicsHandler();
BoardHandler boardHandlerObject = new BoardHandler();

Scanner userInputHandler = new Scanner(System.in);

private char currentTurn;

private int columnSelected;

public void startSelection() {

    currentTurn = turnHandlerObject.getCurrentTurn();

    graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("Player " + currentTurn
            + " please select a column", 0);

    columnSelected = userInputHandler.nextInt();

    if (boardHandlerObject.checkSelectionValidity(columnSelected,
            currentTurn) == 0) {

        graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen(
                "Symbol placed successfully", 0);
        graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("", 3);

        turnHandlerObject.changeCurrentTurn();
        boardHandlerObject.refreshBoard();
    }

    else {

        graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("Error. Column Full.", 0);
        graphicsHandlerObject.outputTextToScreen("", 3);

        startSelection();
    }
}

}

class WinCheckHandler {

private static char player;

public int checkForWin(int row, int column, char player) {

    BoardHandler boardHandlerObject = new BoardHandler();

    char[][] checkingBoard = boardHandlerObject.getGameBoard();

    WinCheckHandler.player = player;

    if (towerCheck(row, column, checkingBoard) == 1) {

        return 1;
    }

    else if (flatCheck(row, column, checkingBoard) == WinCheckHandler.player) {

        return player;
    }

    else if (diagnalCheck(row, column, checkingBoard) ==  WinCheckHandler.player) {

        return player;
    }


    return 0;
}

private int towerCheck(int row, int column, char[][] checkingBoard) {

    int row1 = row;

    int row2 = row;

    row2 -= 1;

    int row3 = row;

    row3 -= 2;

    int row4 = row;

    row4 -= 3;


    if (checkingBoard[row1][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row2][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row3][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row4][column] == player) {

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

private char flatCheck(int row, int column, char[][] checkingBoard) {

    if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row][column += 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row][column += 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row][column += 1] == player) {

        return player;
    }

    else if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row][column -= 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row][column -= 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row][column -= 1] == player) {

        return player;
    }

    return 0;
}

private char diagnalCheck(int row, int column, char[][] checkingBoard) {

    if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row -= 1][column -= 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row -= 1][column -= 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row -= 1][column -= 1] == player) {

        return player;
    }

    else if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row += 1][column -= 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row += 1][column -= 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row += 1][column -= 1] == player) {

        return player;
    }

    else if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
            && checkingBoard[row += 1][column += 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row += 1][column += 1] == player
            && checkingBoard[row += 1][column += 1] == player) {

        return player;
    }


    return 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The glitch is in the class WinCheckHandler. It is supposed to determine if the recent placement connects four of the player's symbol

Comment: Please elaborate "don't seem to be working properly". What is the method name? What is the expected output for a given input?

Comment: @user2341963 I added all the suggested information into the post

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to get more information on the bug? Not many people will be tempted to help you if you just post your entire program.

Comment: @Zar yes, I have spent a couple of hours trying to fix this bug. Used a debugger to verify that the problem is with that method and that the correct row and column were being submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `flatCheck` and `diagnalCheck` methods you use `-=` and `+=` in your checks. This will alter the value of the `row` and `column` variables which will make the following checks meaningless.

For example:

```
if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
        && checkingBoard[row][column += 1] == player
        && checkingBoard[row][column += 1] == player
        && checkingBoard[row][column += 1] == player) {

    return player;
}

else if (checkingBoard[row][column] == player
        && checkingBoard[row][column -= 1] == player
        && checkingBoard[row][column -= 1] == player
        && checkingBoard[row][column -= 1] == player) {

    return player;
}
```

In the `else if` expression, column will not have the value passed to the method - it will have been decremented a number of times depending on which expressions have passed in the previous clause. This is unlikely to be what you intended.

I would recommend changing all of your code to look more like the following:

```
private boolean playHasFourInRow(int row, int col, char[][] board, int player) {
    return row > 3
        && board[row][col] == player
        && board[row-1][col] == player
        && board[row-2][col] == player
        && board[row-3][col] == player;
}
```

If you are familiar with Java 8 then a better format for the expression might be:

```
return IntStream.range(0, WIN_LENGTH)
    .allMatch(n -> n >= 0 && board[row - n][col] == player);
```

Comment: One thing, even towerCheck doesn't appear to work properly and that does not use any of the things you said to avoid. Any ideas?

Comment: @ColeRiggle you have a number of other bugs in your code as well unfortunately. For example your diagonal checks always start from the end of the set - the current token may be completing a run in the middle. I recommend you use jUnit to add test cases for the checks to find out what is working and what isn't.

Comment: Quick question. How do I compare the returned value of your proposed method?

Comment: Haha yeah this is my first program, maybe it was just a bit too ambitious.

Comment: No it's a great problem to start with. But just concentrate on getting one function (e.g. towerCheck) working with lots of tests and then move onto the next. In my opinion learning to write unit tests is one of the keys to learning to code well.

Comment: Ok, I will try to fix it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ColeRiggle sorry missed your question about booleans on the way through. You can check the value of the boolean directly in an `if` expression: `if (playerHasFourInRow(2, 3, board, 1)) {...`